# Filtering for a pattern using SQL Druid Query

Tags: python, sql, yaml, druid

I have a yaml/config file containing all the filters to run queries on to extract data from a database in Druid. I need a filter to query data that has "O_SA" in the column "tag".

Possible values can be

1. "O_SA, O_IM, O_NO"
2. "O_SA"
3. "RB"

In this case, the correct query would pull 1, 2. I've tried setting the yaml filter to .*O_SA.* but I get an internal server error.

yaml file

```
w_filters:
  tag:
    - .*O_SA.*
```

---

python query

```
w_filters = []
    filters_dic = cfg['w_filters']
    for field in filters_dic.keys():
        w_filters.append(Filter(dimension=field, pattern=filters_dic[field], 
  type='regex'))

w_filter = Filter(type='and', fields=w_filters)
```

I'm getting an unknown exception error when calling this. I feel the way I set up the regex filter is incorrect.